# Hackerrank: Frequency Queries Timeout

Tags: javascript

I know that there are plenty of similar questions on SO on this specific thing, but I have a solution that works for all test cases **EXCEPT** for one (it gets timed out). Is there anyway I can make my code run faster or more efficiently... or do I need to start all over?

My logic:

- I create three arrays.
- Whenever there is a new value, I add it to my data array. At the same time, I add a "1" to my frequency array. The positions should be the same.
- Whenever it is the same value, I simply increase the frequency value for the corresponding value by 1.
- Whenever I need to return a value to say whether or not my array has a value with frequency "_", I just indexOf my frequency and tada if it's there I return 0, else I return 1.

```
function freqQuery(queries) {
    var answer = new Array(),
        data = new Array(),
        frequency = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < queries.length; i++){
        var test = queries[i][0];
        if (test == 1) { // first test
            var place = data.indexOf(queries[i][1]);
            if (place == -1){
                data.push(queries[i][1]);
                frequency.push(1);
            } else {
                frequency[place]++;
            }

        } else if (test == 2) { // second test
            var place = data.indexOf(queries[i][1]);
            if ((place != -1) && (frequency[place] > 0)) {
                frequency[place]--;
            }

        } else if (test == 3) { // third test
            if (frequency.indexOf(queries[i][1]) == -1) {
                answer.push(0);
            } else {
                answer.push(1);
            }
        }
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Link: [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/frequency-queries/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dictionaries-hashmaps)

Comment: what is the test case where it times out?

Comment: @pcalkins Test case 10

Answer (score 0):

Task is in category "Dictionaries and Hashmaps". Instead of data and frequency arrays create object with keys being data values and keys being frequencies. Instead of  using `indexOf` which is `O(n)` you would be doing `frequenciesMap[queries[i][1]]` which is `O(1).`